# Combine Angular Material Tree node with input field

Tags: angular

How can I implement such input fields for checked nodes with Angular Material Tree?
I need to enable input fields for some nodes when they are checked, so that the user can input some values.
The expected UI is supposed to look similarly as the attached figure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6rHb.png)
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.